# Using pandas how to add(math operations) multiple rows between two columns to get a total

Tags: python, pandas, math, addition

I have a csv file with multiple columns that represent office supplies sales.
I want to find the total sales for *pens* (**unit price** and **item** are the two **columns**)
so firstly I sorted the df to search for *pens* under the column **item** and listed its **unit** **price**.
now I cant figure out how to add all of the unit prices for each pen sale. how would I do it?

Comment: You would use `groupby` to gather all items of the same kind together, then use `sum` to find the sums of the groups.

Comment: Provide a sample of your data (`df.head().to_dict()`), the code you've tried, and your expected output.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a slight flaw in the logic you presented, but it is hard without the full context - i.e. sample dataframe, code snippet, etc.

In order to calculate total sales of pen items you would need to calculate the sum(price * quantity) of all sales.

so simple df:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'item': ['pen', 'pen', 'chair'], 
        'price':[5, 5, 10], 
        'qtt': [1, 1, 1]
    }
)
sales = sum(df.loc[df['item']=='pen', 'price'] * df.loc[df['item']=='pen', 'qtt'])
```

learning to deal with slicing is key.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html

Comment: Great answer, I would suggest showing the resulting dataframe after your code though, and/or using a quantity other than `1` for every item to better demonstrate what is going on to get to that result.